# Solr Facet Search-Spell check

Tags: solr

I'm usign Solr facet search on a column of database. It successfully returns the data:

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
  <lst name="facet_queries"/>
  <lst name="facet_fields">
    <lst name="tags">
      <int name="lol">58</int>
      <int name="scienc">58</int>
      <int name="photo">34</int>
      <int name="axiom">27</int>
      <int name="geniu">14</int>
   </lst>
  </lst>
  <lst name="facet_dates"/>
  <lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
```

I want to make sure that only complete words are counted. In the above example you can see counts for'scienc' and 'geniu' that should be for 'science' and 'genius'. How can I achieve this? Can I incorporate spell checking feature?

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with the underlying `fieldType` that you have associated with your tags field. The field value is most likely being stemmed or having other analyzers associated with it. I would suggest one of two things:

1. Remove the stemming and/or other processing to prevent the words from appearing as partial.
2. (Recommended) Create a separate field `tags_facet` with `fieldType="string"` in your schema.xml and use a [copyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) directive to copy the values feed into your original `tags` field. Then facet on this new `tags_face`t field.

Answer (score 0):

Use the copyField feature of Solr to copy the original field to one with a string fieldType. If the values are a set of words, instead of string, you could use a whitespace tokenised fieldtype (without ngrams of course.)